# Plugins to look at which lines might allocate

Tags: ide

Are there any plugins/packages to Emacs or other ides that highlight lines of code that could perform allocations?

Googled to no avail

(Can be useful for getting a quick look at potential bottlenecks in code etc etc etc etc)